# How to define user defined java runtime optional command line arguments

Tags: java, runtime, optional-parameters

Instead of giving parameters to my java program in run time with

```
java myprogram "Analyse_Dnase" "Analyse_Histone" "Analyse_Tf" "Analyse_Gene" "Not_Analyse_Kegg_Pathway"
```

I want to give parameters to my java program as follows:

```
java myprogram -analyse dnase -analyse histone -analyse tf -analyse gene
```

How to do this?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Well... You already did it.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Apache Commons CLI](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/) library to achieve this.
It provides great flexibility and ease of use.

Here's documentation on detailed [usage](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/usage.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code,
Give "-analyse dnase -analyse histone -analyse tf -analyse gene" as input.

public static void main(String... args){
      StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer("");
      for(String stringLocal : args){
            buffer.append(" "+stringLocal);
      }
              String fullString = buffer.toString();
              String[] strings = fullString.split("-");
              for(String stringFinal : strings){
                        stringFinal = stringFinal.trim();
                        stringFinal = stringFinal.replace(' ', '_');
                        System.out.println(stringFinal);
        }
}
Then the result will be 
analyse_dnase
analyse_histone
analyse_tf
analyse_gene